# Validating and showing errors in custom editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have custom editor in my plugin with some text fields at top and a Table Viewer below. One of the fields on the top is required. If left blank I want to show a error message on top in editor and in problems view of eclipse.

Using `IMarker` I am able to show error in Problems view but how to highlight the same in editor for the user.

Below is the screen shot of Editor I am creating (not actual but similar to this)

[Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJhuP.png)

The editor content is based on an XML file. The attributes present on the child node of the root are displayed in table and attributes on root node displayed  in text fields above the table. It is not a multipage editor - I am not providing source view for user to edit just this UI.

The text field at top I need to validate like if left blank provide an error message and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Use marker annotations in your annotation model, see the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors_annotations.htm)

Comment: greg - The above link talks about providing annotations on Editors that are extending TextEditor but in my case I am just providing UI for editing there is no source editor. Can you provide some pointers as to how can I go about providing annotations or Error Messages for UI editors.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'UI editor'. You need to tell us a lot more about the structure of this editor.